# "Undefined is not a Function " error. Why is not working?

Tags: react-native

```
 import React from "react"; import {StackNavigator} from "react-navigation"; import StartScreen from "../screens/start";


 export default StackNavigator( {   Start: {
     screen: StartScreen   } }, {   initialRouteName:"Start",   navigationOptions:{
     headerSryle:{
       backgroundColor:"#f4511e"
     },
     headerTitleStyle:{
       textAlign:"center",
       alignSelf:"center",
       fontSize:20,
       color:"#fff",
       fontWeight:"bold"
     }   }  } )
```

[image: phone screenshot showing error]

Comment: Can you please post an screenshot of the error or what is undefined ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Instead of posting an image of text, like the error message, it is better to include the text in the question as text is searchable and accessible. You might want to [edit] the question to include more context, and review if you meant `headerSryle` instead of `headerStyle`.

Comment: You aren't giving us enough to work with. The error does not appear to be in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

You should write something like:

```
const HomeStack = StackNavigator({ ...
```

and then

```
export default HomeStack;
```